# Dismissing of UIImagePickerController dismisses presenting view controller also

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working on a project that uses tabbar system. One of the item of tabbar is JobPostingViewController. I Embed it in UINavigationController. There is a UIButton called add new job in this view controller .I implemented pushviewcontroller to go CreateJobPostViewController. There I need to add UIImagePickerController to choose the image. When i tap done button or choose an image from library it dismisses to JobPostingViewController. But it should go to the CreateJobPostViewController.
Any one please help me. Thanks in advance.

You can see the issue here:
[image]

Code in JobPostingViewController

```
 @IBAction func openCreateJob(sender: AnyObject) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CreateJobPostViewController") as! CreateJobPostViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Code in CreateJobPostViewController

```
   @IBAction func addImages(sender: AnyObject) {
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I've never seen this issue before. `imagePicker ` seems to already be defined before `addImages` is called. Why? is that being used somewhere else? Is there other code working at the same time? Also you are calling `picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated` you are suppose to ask the parent (presentingViewController) to dismiss the modal controller (i.e. `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated`) not tell the presented to dismiss itself.

Comment: It does not make another sense defining imagePicker as global variable.It is not used anywhere. I tried both options you suggest to dismiss the image picker view controller. I was tired of finding the solution and I use another way. Thank you for your suggestion. @ Simon McLoughlin

Comment: Can you post more code or explain the layout of the app more. There are many people highlighting various similar issues and solutions. Is `JobPostingViewController` a container view? or inside a container view? How is this screen opened? when the picker is dismissed it will trigger the `viewWillAppear` / `viewDidAppear`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` methods on `CreateJobPostViewController`. Are you doing anything inside these methods?

Comment: When picker is dismissed neither of the methods are called. It directly load the tab bar items. I have created a method to create a tab bar inside a class named TabViewController. It directly calls that method and tabbar is reloaded.

Comment: could you try adding:

`imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext` inside `addImages` before you present it

Comment: thanks a lot Simon. After all i fix the problem. Actually there was a problem in creating tabbar programmatically. I solved the problem because of you. Thanks a lot. I appreciate it. :) :) :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Adding Picker as subview***

try to add the imagepicker as a subview to your CreateJobPostViewController insted of presenting it and then remove it from parent in the delegtes

```
@IBAction func openCreateJob(sender: AnyObject) {

var picker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
picker.delegate = self
picker.allowsEditing = false
picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
self.addChildViewController(picker)
picker.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
self.view!.addSubview(picker.view!)
}
```

and then

```
 func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {

    picker.view!.removeFromSuperview()
    picker.removeFromParentViewController()
    }
```

***For presenting***

showing picker over currentcontext with options like edit cancel choose,

use `picker.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext`  //before presenting 
it

```
 presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: i want to show picker above navigation bar and tab bar that means over whole screen. Can you please help me?

Comment: You can do that by adding your picker controller as subview of self.navigationcontroller like  [self.navigationController.view addSubview:picker] by

Answer (score 26):

**Fixed the issue  by setting the image picker's modalPresentationStyle to "OverCurrentContext":**

```
picker.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

Comment: This actually fixed it for me. The viewWillDisappear method was not longer called on the originating view controller.

Comment: This is the right way to do it. The accepted answer is a Hacky one.

Answer (score 6):

You could use:

```
picker.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

but depending on your screen layout, it may be better to use:

```
picker.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
```

otherwise your "cancel", "retake" and "use photo" buttons may not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, I solved it using the storyboard (Xcode v9.2)

1 - Go to the storyboard, where is your ViewController, select it

[image: Select ViewController]

2 - Set Presentation as: Current Context

[image: Set current context]

Note: If it does not work Current Context, select Over Current Context

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to present the picker *over* an iOS 13 popover view controller. To stop the camera from dismissing my popover view controller I had to change the picker's modalPresentationStyle to popover. See below:

```swift
picker.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
```