# Delegate methods are not called on adding a view controller's as sub view

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I am opening TOCropViewController from a ViewController.The following code is opening the view of TOCropViewController  and cropping is also working fine.But the Cancel and Done button are not working.I guess the delegate methods are not called.So guys can any body help me.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "my-photo")
cropViewController = TOCropViewController(image: image!)
cropViewController.delegate = self
addChildViewController(cropViewController)            
view!.addSubview(cropViewController.view!)
cropViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

If I use following code instead both the button works fine.But I need to open a view controller like above.

```
self.present(cropViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: The library was built to work as a modal viewController. You either need to change your UI to work with that, modify the library to accept both ways, or implement the logic yourself the way you need it

Comment: I had this problem so i want this way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167027/dismissing-of-uiimagepickercontroller-dismisses-presenting-view-controller-also

Comment: you got some very bad advice in this other question. This is not necessary at all and much more complicated than the way apple suggest to use it. I would un accept that answer as its going to cause you a lot more trouble. I will ask you for more details on the other question and try debug that

Comment: Thanks I believe you. Can you find me a better way?